# How to check return value using jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**I have this code IN JS:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select_vendor').bind('change', function(){
        var vendor_no = $('#vendor_no').val();

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '<?php echo site_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/check');?>',
            data: {vendor_no: vendor_no},
            success: function(data) {
                if (there is data returned by function) {
                    $('#show_orders').html(data); 
                } else {
                    alert('No Data!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
function check() {
    $this->load->model('vendor_model');

    $data = $this->vendor_model->CheckVendor($this->input->get('vendor_no'));

    $this->load->view('show_items',$data);
}
```

if there is data returned by the function, i want to display the data, else show alert message. How to check if data contains values? thanks.

Comment: Will you return blank page if there is no data to display?

Comment: no, i just want to show the alert window when no data is returned.

Comment: Yeah but what do you mean by no data? What will controller return in case of `no data`?

Comment: what i mean is if NULL is returned in  $this->vendor_model->CheckVendor($this->input->get('vendor_no')), alert window will be shown.

Comment: It depends on how you render the view with NULL data here... `$this->load->view('show_items',$data);`

Answer (score 0):

Check if `data` is undefined:

```
success: function(data) {
   if (data && data != null) {
      // data is not undefined
      $('#show_orders').html(data);
   } else {
      alert('No Data!');
   }
}
```

Comment: it still go to $('#show_orders').html(data) even if $data is NULL.

Comment: `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Your controller will always return data, since you're loading a view.

```
$this->load->view('show_items',$data); //this will return a html code i suppose.
```

You should use a return variable, such a response flag to ajax. I strongly advise to use json return to your ajax request. Define dataType: "json" in ajax parameters.

Something like:

```
$myReturn = array();
$data = $this->vendor_model->CheckVendor($this->input->get('vendor_no'));

if(is_null($data) || empty($data)){ // no data at all
   $myReturn['success'] = false;

}else{
   $myReturn['success'] = true;       
   $myReturn['data'] = $data; //data filled
}
return json_encode($myReturn);
```

Then you could check in ajax request:

```
success: function(data) {
   if (data.success) {
      // flag success is not false, so there is data.
      $('#show_orders').html(data.data); // .data is the index specified on controller
   } else {
      alert('No Data!');
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi! i added the dataType: 'json', to my ajax parameters but it no longer performs my controller. 
`code` $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            url: '<?php echo site_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/check');?>',
            data: {vendor_no: vendor_no},
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#show_orders').html(data.data); 
                } else {
                    alert('No Data!');
                }
            }
        });

Comment: Be aware, this piece of code will not work correctly:

    `url: '<?php echo site_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/check');?>'`



Try this:
    `url: "<?php echo site_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/check');?>"` //look at double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to return blank page if the `$data` is null.

For that update your **controller** like this,

```
function check() {
    $this->load->model('vendor_model');

    $data = $this->vendor_model->CheckVendor($this->input->get('vendor_no'));

    if(is_null($data) || empty($data)){
      echo "";
      exit;
    } else {
      $this->load->view('show_items',$data);
    }
}
```

Now in JS check if the returned page is blank or not, Like this:

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '<?php echo site_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/check');?>',
            data: {vendor_no: vendor_no},
            success: function(data) {
                if (data!="") {
                    $('#show_orders').html(data); 
                } else {
                    alert('No Data!');
                }
            }
        });
```

> Make sure it's not the best method you should follow. Better method would be to return json response along with content and status. If status is true then only display the data.